# JQ separate output

Tags: json, format, jq, jsonlines

i have a json formatted in this way :

```
{
  "first_name": "Mario",
  "last_name": "Bros",
  "email": "mario.bros@mario.com",

}
{
  "first_name": "Luigi",
  "last_name": "Bros",
  "email": "luigi.bros@mario.com",

}
```

I have this output with

```
jq --compact-output 'select(.contact_type | contains("tecnico")) | {FirstName: .first_name},{LastName: .last_name},{Email: .email}'

{"FirstName":"Mario"}
{"LastName":"Bros"}
{"Email":"mario.bros@mario.com"}
{"FirstName":"Luigi"}
{"LastName":"Bros"}
{"Email":"luigi.bros@mario.com"}
```

I want split with space Mario from Luigi.

Comment: Can you post the exact output needed?

Comment: Your input doesn't seem to match your command, there is no `tecnico` anywhere to be seen.

Comment: @Inian I think OP wants a blank line between third and fourth lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input is fixed and that each object has a "technico" field, you can run the following:

```
jq -r -c '
  select(.contact_type | contains("tecnico"))
  | {FirstName: .first_name},{LastName: .last_name},{Email: .email}, ""
'
```

The -r option suppresses the quotation marks around the top-level string, and the trailing `, ""` has the effect of adding a new-line after each object.

If you only want the additional blank lines between the objects, then you might find it easier to use a complementary tool such as `sed` or `awk`.  However, here is a jq-only solution that assumes jq has been called with the -n option in addition to -r -c:

```
def nl(stream):
  foreach stream as $s (-1; .+1; if . > 0 then "" else empty end, $s);

nl(inputs | select(.contact_type | contains("tecnico"))
| if type == "string"
  then . 
  else {FirstName: .first_name},{LastName: .last_name},{Email: .email} 
  end
```